# Reflexive norm-closed subalgebras of $B(X)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space, and let $B(X)$ denote the set of all bounded linear operators $X\to X$.
Does there exist a norm-closed subalgebra $A\subseteq B(X)$ with the following properties?

1. A is unital.
2. A is reflexive as a Banach space.
3. *Every* closed maximal left ideal has *infinite* codimension.

.

PS: The following are equivalent for $A$

- Every closed maximal left ideal of $A$ has infinite codimension.
- Every primitive ideal of $A$ has infinite codimension.
- Every irreducible representation of $A$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299311/reflexive-operator-algebra

Comment: I guess the algebra of Hilbert-Schmidt operators on $l^2$ satisfies 2 and 3, but of course it isn't unital.

Comment: @TomaszKania Special thanks you for your reply, for I am aware of your level of knowledge and expertise in the field, as anybody would who's even remotely familiar with this field. My amateur attempts to produce reflexive operator algebras with the 3rd property from reflexive subspaces did not get me so far.

Comment: @NikWeaver Professor Weaver, I am so glad to see your reply. There are relatively common examples when one drops one of the 3 conditions above. If A is a unital Banach algebra, which is also a Hilbert space, then it is finite dimensional (e.g., https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1963-11035-6) 

For another example, the algebra $K(l^2)$ of compact operators is not reflexive, but has the other 2 properties.

Comment: Mmm, I don't think $K(l^2)$ has a unit. One approach to constructing an example would be to first identify a Banach algebra with the three properties, then try to find a matricial norm structure extending the original norm which makes the product completely contractive. Then by general theory it will be (completely) isometrically isomorphic to a subalgebra of $B(H)$.

Comment: Are there even any infinite dimensional unital Banach algebras which are reflexive as Banach spaces?

Comment: @NikWeaver Sorry for the mistake. I must have gotten mixed up with the link Tomasz Kania directed me to. $K(l^2)$ is amenable, has a bounded approximate identity, but no identity for sure. 

Could you open up what you meant by "first identify a Banach algebra with the three properties"? Will this lead to an existence or a non-existence?

Comment: @NikWeaver $\ell^p$ ($1<p<\infty$) with pointwise operations are reflexive Banach algebras. One may attach a unit without losing reflexivity.

Comment: @NikWeaver, when you talk about Hilbert-Schmidt operators, it is not quite an example for 2 and 3 since most likely Onur wants a closed subalgebra of $B(X)$.

Comment: @TomaszKania Any Banach algebra, which is a dual Banach space, with a separately weak* continuous multiplication can be embedded into $B(X)$ for some reflexive Banach space $X$ via a weak* continuous isometry [Corollary 3.8 in doi:10.4064/sm178-3-3]. When $A$ is reflexive itseft, then $A$ is trivially a subalgebra of $B(A)$. What Hilbert-Schmidt algebra misses is, indeed, the identity.

Comment: Attaching a unit to an algebra would create an ideal of codimension 1. Thus, even if $A$ has no finite codimensional maximal left ideals, $A$ with unit attached does not have the same property.

Comment: Since this now has a bounty, can you please edit your question to clarify whether A is supposed to be a **norm-closed** subalgebra of B(X)? This ambiguity seems to have created some confusion in comments.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thank you for the notice, I edited as suggested.